# XPATH - how to use multiple operators on one query

Tags: xpath

I am scraping a web URL that looks like this:

```
www.example.com/pages/popup/popup_report_review.aspx?bikeReviewID=6582049&PageTypeID=9&width=900&height=500
```

I only want the ID number from it. I tried to run this query first to start the parsing after the "=" and it works perfectly:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(//a[@id='webpage_url']/@href, '='))
```

So now I have: `6582049&PageTypeID=9&width=900&height=500`

I now want to run another query to just leave me with the ID number so I think this is the one:

```
substring(//a[@id='webpage_url']/@href,1,7)
```

This leaves me with only 7 characters. They both work perfectly independently, but I cannot get them to run together. I tried using 'and' but that returns me a number 1.. This is what I did:

```
normalize-space(substring-after(//a[@id='webpage_url']/@href, '=')) and substring(//a[@id='webpage_url']/@href,1,7)
```

Does anyone know how I can combine both queries or is there a better way to get this ID? Thanks in advance doe any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use this query:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//a[@id='webpage_url']/@href, '='), '&amp;')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this returns no value at all for some reason.

Comment: If I change the symbol to a standard "&" then it works fine! Thanks very much indeed, this will be very handy.

Comment: You're right, I wrote this expression with XSLT in mind; if you're using it in another context, you can use the literal character instead of its entity.

Comment: Thanks again for helping out, really appreciate it. Have a good day.